# Creating a cluster before sending a job to dataproc programmatically

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to schedule a PySpark Job. I followed the GCP documentation and ended up deploying a little python script to App Engine which does the following :

- authenticate using a service account
- submit a job to a cluster

The problem is, I need the cluster to be up and running otherwise the job won't be sent (duh !) but I don't want the cluster to always be up and running, especially since my job needs to run once a month.

I wanted to add the creation of a cluster in my python script but the call is asynchronous (it makes an HTTP request) and thus my job is submitted after the cluster creation call but before the cluster is really up and running.

How could I do ?

I'd like something cleaner than just waiting for a few minutes in my script !

Thanks

EDIT : Here's what my code looks like so far :

To launch the job

```
class EnqueueTaskHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        task = taskqueue.add(
            url='/run',
            target='worker')

        self.response.write(
            'Task {} enqueued, ETA {}.'.format(task.name, task.eta))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/launch', EnqueueTaskHandler)], debug=True)
```

The job

```
class CronEventHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def create_cluster(self, dataproc, project, zone, region, cluster_name):
        zone_uri = 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{}/zones/{}'.format(project, zone)
        cluster_data = {...}

        dataproc.projects().regions().clusters().create(
            projectId=project,
            region=region,
            body=cluster_data).execute()

    def wait_for_cluster(self, dataproc, project, region, clustername):
        print('Waiting for cluster to run...')
        while True:
            result = dataproc.projects().regions().clusters().get(
            projectId=project,
            region=region,
            clusterName=clustername).execute()
            # Handle exceptions
            if result['status']['state'] != 'RUNNING':
                time.sleep(60)
            else:
                return result

    def wait_for_job(self, dataproc, project, region, job_id):
        print('Waiting for job to finish...')
        while True:
            result = dataproc.projects().regions().jobs().get(
                projectId=project,
                region=region,
                jobId=job_id).execute()
            # Handle exceptions
            print(result['status']['state'])
            if result['status']['state'] == 'ERROR' or result['status']['state'] == 'DONE':
                return result
            else:
                time.sleep(60)

    def submit_job(self, dataproc, project, region, clusterName):
        job = {...}
        result = dataproc.projects().regions().jobs().submit(projectId=project,region=region,body=job).execute()
        return result['reference']['jobId']


    def post(self):
        dataproc = googleapiclient.discovery.build('dataproc', 'v1')

        project = '...'
        region = "..."
        zone = "..."
        clusterName = '...'

        self.create_cluster(dataproc, project, zone, region, clusterName)
        self.wait_for_cluster(dataproc, project, region, clusterName)
        job_id = self.submit_job(dataproc,project,region,clusterName)
        self.wait_for_job(dataproc,project,region,job_id)
        dataproc.projects().regions().clusters().delete(projectId=project, region=region, clusterName=clusterName).execute()
        self.response.write("JOB SENT")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/run', CronEventHandler)], debug=True)
```

Everything works until the deletion of the cluster. At this point I get a "DeadlineExceededError: The overall deadline for responding to the HTTP request was exceeded." Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to general polling either through `list` or `get` requests on the Cluster or the Operation returned with the CreateCluster request, for single-use clusters like this you can also consider using the [Dataproc Workflows API](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/workflows/overview) and possibly its [InstantiateInline interface](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/projects.regions.workflowTemplates/instantiateInline) if you don't want to use full-fledged workflow templates; in this API you use a single request to specify cluster settings along with jobs to submit, and the jobs will automatically run as soon as the cluster is ready to take it, after which the cluster will be deleted automatically.

Comment: thank you for your input, I used the API and now almost everything works except for the "DeadlineExceededError: The overall deadline for responding to the HTTP request was exceeded." error !

Comment: Is there a method to call templates from python code ? I can't seem to find it !

Comment: I found how to call templates API but the job fails. I don't know why since it runs well when I launch it manually or when I launch it with the REST API. The error is the same as described here :https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17131

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Cloud Dataproc API](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/) to [`create`](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.clusters/create), [`delete`](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.clusters/delete) and [`list`](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.clusters/list) clusters.

The `list` operation can be (repeatedly) performed after `create` and `delete` operations to confirm that they completed successfully, since it provides the [`ClusterStatus`](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.clusters#clusterstatus) of the clusters in the results with the relevant [`State`](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.clusters#state) information:

```
UNKNOWN     The cluster state is unknown.
CREATING    The cluster is being created and set up. It is not ready for use.
RUNNING     The cluster is currently running and healthy. It is ready for use.
ERROR       The cluster encountered an error. It is not ready for use.
DELETING    The cluster is being deleted. It cannot be used.
UPDATING    The cluster is being updated. It continues to accept and process jobs.
```

To prevent plain waiting between the (repeated) `list` invocations (in general not a good thing to do on GAE) you can enqueue delayed tasks in a [push task queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/#push_queues) (with the relevant context information) allowing you to perform such `list` operations at a later time. For example, in python, see [`taskqueue.add()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.taskqueue):

> - countdown -- Time in seconds into the future that this task should run or be leased. Defaults to zero. Do not specify this argument if
>     you specified an eta.
> - eta -- A `datetime.datetime` that specifies the absolute earliest time at which the task should run. You cannot specify this argument if
>     the countdown argument is specified. This argument can be time
>     zone-aware or time zone-naive, or set to a time in the past. If the
>     argument is set to None, the default value is now. For pull tasks, no
>     worker can lease the task before the time indicated by the eta
>     argument.

If at the task execution time the result indicates the operation of interest is still in progress simply enqueue another such delayed task - effectively polling but without an actual wait/sleep.

Comment: thank you for your input, I used the API and now almost everything works except for the "DeadlineExceededError: ! Do you know if this is because I query too much about the job state before deleting the cluster ? Thank you !

Comment: There are multiple kinds of `DeadlineExceededError`, can you tell which one? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors

Comment: google.appengine.runtime.DeadlineExceededError. But I understand that it times out since my job runs for like 20min and then is supposed to trash the cluster. But in the end it only submits the job and at a certain point in time I get this error. The job succeeds but then the deletion of the cluster does not happen

Comment: You're still doing all the waiting for job or cluster inside the same request handler and that takes too long. Don't wait, just enqueue a delayed task, which will be a different request and in that request you do the check and trigger another task. Basically breaking a single request into a chained sequence of tasks, each with a rather short response time.

Comment: If you submit your cluster and job through Workflows as @Dennis Huo suggests, you will not have to do any polling or error handling. Its just one fire and forget request.

Comment: @tix yes that's what I'm trying to do but I can't seem to find the corresponding API call from python to call templates.