# PySpark Job fails with workflow template

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, bigdata, google-cloud-dataproc

To follow with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49790130/creating-a-cluster-before-sending-a-job-to-dataproc-programmatically) I decided to try the workflow template API.

Here's what it looks like :

```
gcloud beta dataproc workflow-templates create lifestage-workflow --region europe-west2
gcloud beta dataproc workflow-templates set-managed-cluster lifestage-workflow \
  --master-machine-type n1-standard-8 \
  --worker-machine-type n1-standard-16 \
  --num-workers 6 \
  --cluster-name lifestage-workflow-cluster \
  --initialization-actions gs://..../init.sh \
  --zone europe-west2-b \
  --region europe-west2 \

gcloud beta dataproc workflow-templates add-job pyspark gs://.../main.py \
--step-id prediction \
--region europe-west2 \
--workflow-template lifestage-workflow \
--jars gs://.../custom.jar \
--py-files gs://.../jobs.zip,gs://.../config.ini \
-- --job predict --conf config.ini
```

The template is correctly created.
The job works when I run it manually from one of my already existing clusters. It also runs when I use an existing cluster instead of asking the workflow to create one.

The thing is I want the cluster to be created before running the job and deleted just after, that's why I'm using a **managed cluster**.

But with the managed cluster I just can't make it run. I tried to use the same configuration as my existing clusters but it doesn't change anything.
I always get the same [error](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17131).

Any idea why my job runs perfectly except for when it is run from a generated cluster ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your flow. I believe this is correct, and linked JIRA should have been fixed in Dataproc 1.2 (Spark 2.2.1). That said, I would like to compare successful and failing job metadata but for this I need a bit more information than can be shared on SO. Please reach out to us on dataproc-feedback[at]google.com. Only you and google engineers can read your thread.

Comment: Thank you ! I sent a mail with logs for SUCCESS case and FAILURE case !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem came from the version of the managed cluster. 
By default the image version was 1.2.31 and my existing cluster was using the image 1.2.28. 
 When I changed the config to add **--image-version=1.2.28** it worked.

Dataproc image 1.2.31 Upgraded Spark to 2.2.1 which introduced [SPARK-22472]:

> SPARK-22472: added null check for top-level primitive types. Before
>   this release, for datasets having top-level primitive types, and it
>   has null values, it might return some unexpected results. For example,
>   let’s say we have a parquet file with schema , and we read it
>   into Scala Int. If column a has null values, when transformation is
>   applied some unexpected value can be returned.

This likely added just enough generated code to take classes of 64k limit.